# Refreshing Form fields in jquery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How to reset the form fields which may be **dynamically** generated and are in a jQuery tab?
When the user moves from one tab to another the first tab with form text fields should be reset and upon revisiting the tab the fields should be reset..

Have used the function:

```
resetForm(formId){
    $(’#’+formId)[0].reset();
}
```

The issue is that the tab contains form fields which are dynamically created (generated on add more).

How do we remove the clear the form fields in such a case.

Comment: You want to clear the form fields? Clear their values or delete them from the HTML?

Comment: Make sure your dynamically added form elements have to be inside the form tag. Otherwise `reset()` will not work for them. You have to manually clear your textboxes instead.

Comment: If the form is loaded onto the DOM, it should work the way you are coding.

Comment: Maybe a code example on the markup would help more.

Answer (score 0):

This clears all form values:

```
$('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, teaxarea').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a common class for all the inputs and based on the events like onfocus or blur you can reset their values.
For example

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").onfocus = function() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have:

```
<div id="container>
    <form ...>
    ... dynamically generated forms etc
    <form ...>
</div>
```

then you can select all forms inside this container like that:

```
$('#container form').each(function(){
        $(this)[0].reset();
    });
```

This will fire given function for all forms selected where $(this) is the current form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to clear the fields that are dynamically created in a form?

Then is this what you need?

```
resetForm(formId) { 
    $("input, textarea, select", $("#" + formId)).val(''); // Or .text('');
}
```

Comment: What about `<select>`, `<textarea>` `<button>`?

Comment: @Starx I have edited the answer, though I don't know if you can and should reset a button?

Comment: Your statement will also evaluate to `$("#"+formId).val('')`. A form does not have a value field.

Comment: @Starx Actually, the formId is a second parameter in jQuery-function. It sets the context for the first parameter: `"input, textarea, select"`. See reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: My bad, I got confused with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some class to the fields you add dynamically to the form. for example: "dynamically_added". So when you move to another tab, I would do something like:

```
    var form_values;
    $( ".selector" ).tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) { 
            if (ui.index != 0) { //if I didn't clicked on the first tab
                save_form_fields();
                $( ".dynamically_added" ).remove();
                $("#" + formId).reset();
            }
            else {
                add_dynamic_fields();
                restore_form_values();
            }
        }
    });
```

I didn't test the code but I hope it helps. If not, let me know and I will think of something else.

Comment: This could work, but is it the best way to remove the element from DOM? Wouldn't it be better to just clear the values of elements?

Comment: The question is what do you mean by "best way" - performance? cross browser?. I guess that if you don't need to support IE6, than it's pretty much the best way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it in a "better way" =) I was thinking that you'd need more code to re-create the elements you remove. So you could say performance in a way.

Comment: Sorry, just missed the "restore" part of the question. I guess that the code that creates the elements exists. So if you save the values of the existing fields before leaving the form, you can return them after you return to the first tab with adding "else" to my code.